# PHP Strict Standards: Non-static method File_Find::glob() should not be called statically in

Tags: php

I have a php script with a search field that calls a bash script via ssh2, returns the found data/files and then displays them in a browser. The only time it will not return a list of files is when I navigate to a folder that has spaces in the folder name i.e.( folder/folder2 a bbb/ ). At this point I get a message in the php_errors.log

> (PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method File_Find::glob() should not be called statically in /var/www/html/searchapi.php on line 16 ), here's line 16

```
 $files = &File_Find::glob($pattern,"$path", 'shell');
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: What isn't clear about that error message?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create an instance of the `File_Find` class to use the `glob()` method.

The reason you were down-voted is because some quick Googling would have told you what the difference between static and non-static methods are, from which you may have been able to determine what the error message actually meant.

Comment: ...and that the op asked us to help fix some code without providing the code which needed fixing; perhaps the solution might be to amend the method declaration. And that this question has been asked and answered onn stackoverflow many times before.

Comment: and I don't see how the reported error message relates to whether a folder has spaces in the name

Comment: I googled and googled and exhausted my limited knowledge on the subject. Thanks for your inputs but still not resolved. I'll keep researching.